# Интернет магазин

Tags: php

Сделал в подобие интернет магазина. Данные берутся из базы, но сделал кнопку для перехода на другую страницу. И при переходе на должно быть отображено описание того товара, на которую кликнули.

Помогите пожалуйста.

```html
<div class="main">
  <?php 
   include("header.php"); ?>
  <?php 
   include ("menu.php"); ?>
  <div class=magazin>
    <?php 
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "usbw", "litle");
 if ($link){
$sql ="SELECT * FROM `products`";
  $result= mysqli_query($link, $sql);
 $_POST['hasce']="shop1.php";
  if ($result){
   while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "
    <div>
      <div><h1>".$r['name']."</h1> 
      <h1>".$r['price']."</h1>
      <img src=".$r['src']." ></div>
      <p>".$r['description']."</p>
      <a href='shop1.php'>".Smatret."</a>
      </div> 
    ";
   }
  }
  else {
   echo "harcum";
  }
 }
 else {
  echo "kapi xndir";
 }?>
  </div>
  <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: не вижу вопроса.

Comment: Как сделать чтобы кнопка сматрет для каждово тавара была своя а не первая каторый я указал